# Docker swarm manager pending status

Tags: windows, docker

I have 2 windows 2016 server with container services enabled. I have installed docker in both the machines.
Now I am trying to install docker cluster swarm mode. But when run:

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.233.131 > test.txt
```

it is stuck and does not display any output.

When I run docker info,  it showing

```
Swarm: pending ( manager node).
```

Kindly help me to resolve.  What have I missed?

```
Containers: 6  Running: 0  Paused: 0  Stopped: 6 Images: 5 Server
Version: 17.03.0-ee-1 Storage Driver: windowsfilter  Windows: Logging
Driver: json-file Plugins:  Volume: local  Network: l2bridge l2tunnel
nat null overlay transparent Swarm: pending  NodeID: l0cavlw31jzh4xbg34gqkubah  Is Manager: true  ClusterID:
bi188mb7kcd0ct87c1ia1xha3  Managers: 1  Nodes: 1  Orchestration:  
Task History Retention Limit: 5  Raft:   Snapshot Interval: 10000  
Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0   Heartbeat Tick: 1   Election
Tick: 3  Dispatcher:   Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds  CA Configuration: 
Expiry Duration: 3 months  Node Address: 192.168.233.131  Manager
Addresses:
  0.0.0.0:2377 Default Isolation: process Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 (14393.1480.amd64fre.rs1_release.170706-2004) Operating System:
Windows Server 2016 Standard OSType: windows Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1 Total Memory: 1.999 GiB Name: WIN-NGCG1EF8Q2E ID:
EAT6:KLZD:BQAY:TXGV:4LR4:POTH:3VSJ:OEQO:TBAN:L322:QFNC:4V3J Docker
Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker Debug Mode (client): false Debug Mode
(server): false Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/ Experimental:
false Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: Don't redirect output to a file. First check them on console. Also use `docker swarm leave` to discard the old swarm. Follow this article and see if it helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/swarm-mode

Comment: thanks for your help it works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C:\> docker swarm init --advertise-addr=HOSTIPADDRESS --listen-addr HOSTIPADDRESS:2377
```

i have typed the above command format it works thanks @Tarun Lalwani